# How do I create a price variable that will have a different value in every list tile when expanded?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I create a price variable that will have a different value in every list tile when expanded?

I want to make the subtitle value of the expanded tile to be different on on every tile. where I have "R24", I want to have a different price for every item on the list tile. when I add the price variable in the constructor, the list throws an error that says `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new TileApp());
}

class TileApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Center(
            child: Text('ExpansionTile App'),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.shopping_basket,
            size:35)
          ],
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new StuffInTiles(listOfTiles[index]);
          },
          itemCount: listOfTiles.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StuffInTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyTile myTile;
  StuffInTiles(this.myTile);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(myTile);
  }

  Widget _buildTiles(MyTile t) {
    if (t.children.isEmpty)
      return new ListTile(
          dense: true,
          enabled: true,
          isThreeLine: false,
          onLongPress: () => print("long press"),
          onTap: () => print("tap"),
          subtitle: new Text(t.price.toString()),
          leading: new Text("Leading"),
          selected: true,
          trailing:
              GestureDetector(child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.green)),
          title: new Text(t.title));

    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<int>(3),
      title: new Text(t.title),
      children: t.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class MyTile {
  String title;
  int price;

  List<MyTile> children;

  MyTile(this.price,this.title, [this.children = const <MyTile>[]]);
}

List<MyTile> listOfTiles = <MyTile>[
  new MyTile(
    'Gin Cocktails',
    <MyTile>[
      new MyTile('Clover Club'),
      new MyTile('Tanqueray Sling'),
      new MyTile('1934 Cosmo'),
    ],
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'Beers & Ciders',
    <MyTile>[
      new MyTile('Heineken NRB'),
      new MyTile('Corona'),
    ],
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'Wine List',
    <MyTile>[
      new MyTile('Wine By The Glass'),
      new MyTile('White Wine'),
      new MyTile(
        'Red Wine',
        <MyTile>[
          new MyTile('Spier Signature Merlot'),
          new MyTile('Glenelly Glass Collection'),
          new MyTile('Nederburg Baronnen '),
          new MyTile('Nero D’Avola '),
          new MyTile('Reyneke Organic Cab Sav/Merlot '),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
];
```

Comment: where are your price?

Comment: The price is in the MyTile Class

Comment: I only see name there.

Comment: but can you see the MyTile class?

Comment: yes, I saw you declare the price, but you not using it?

Comment: when I add the price variable in the constructor, the list throws an error that says `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int`

Comment: maybe show us where you add?

Answer (score 0):

You declared three parameters but only pass two parameters, which is wrong. You need to add one more parameter(price) in `MyTile` constructor.

```
 new MyTile(
         500 // add price here
        'Gin Cocktails',
        <MyTile>[
          new MyTile('Clover Club'),
          new MyTile('Tanqueray Sling'),
          new MyTile('1934 Cosmo'),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: what errors? Make sure you add the price parameter in all `MyTile` constructor.

Comment: Not yet, still busy with it